# What is the command to set title for an image file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, images

I want to set the title of image files (view Properties - tab Details - Title textbox) to be their filenames by running a command from command line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for Windows to somewhere in your PATH and rename it to `exiftools.exe`

Then you can use the following command to update the Title field for each JPG file in the current directory:

```
for %i in (*.jpg) do @exiftool -Title="%~ni" %i
```

By default, exiftool seems to create copies of the originals with the extension `.jpg_original` before modifying them.

Comment: When I run your command I get the error ~ni" i was unexpected at this time. Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a .bat file or .cmd file? If so, you will need to use %%i instead of %i and %%~ni instead of %~ni.

Also, you will need to make sure you have Command Extensions enabled when using cmd.exe

Comment: I run the script by .bat file. I replace %i to %%i and %~ni to %%~ni and it works. Thank you.